# exim4 issue with MX records

Tags: linux, email, smtp, exim

I have a Debian machine running Exim4.

However, when checking the Exim log, I noticed this issue when mailing my own domain:

```
2010-12-14 09:20:01 1PSQ77-0005mG-9w ** root@domain.com: all relevant MX records point to non-existent hosts
2010-12-14 09:20:01 1PSQ77-0005mJ-CH ** root@domain.com: all relevant MX records point to non-existent hosts
```

And when checking MX in dig:

```
# dig mx domain.com
...
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.com.            IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.com.     3600    IN  MX  50 mailprotect.tyneso.com.
domain.com.     3600    IN  MX  10 mailprotect2.tyneso.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mailprotect.tyneso.com. 2082    IN  A   192.168.13.10
mailprotect2.tyneso.com.   2382 IN  A   192.168.13.12

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.22.11#53(192.168.22.11)
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 14 09:21:22 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 126
```

Yet I am able to ping and telnet the Barracuda server:

```
# ping mailprotect2.tyneso.com.
PING mailprotect2.tyneso.com (192.168.13.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.13.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.17 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.13.12: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.647 ms

--- mailprotect2.tyneso.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 5066ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.647/2.910/5.174/2.264 ms

# telnet mailprotect2.tyneso.com 25
Trying 192.168.13.12...
Connected to mailprotect2.tyneso.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ***************************************************************
^]
```

Any clue what might cause Exim to spit out those errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that the MX records are in the RFC1918 private range. By default exim refuses to connect to private IPS. Take a look in your config for a line like this:

```
ignore_target_hosts = 0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8 : 192.168.0.0/16 : 172.16.0.0/12 : 10.0.0.0/8 : 169.254.0.0/16
```

and modify it to suit your needs.